# Typhoon parameter injection with initalizer crashing app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, typhoon

i want to use Typhoon ([GitHub](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon) & [WebSite](http://typhoonframework.org/)) for dependency injection in my app. I use Swift Version 3 and Typhoon 3.6. Unfortunately my app is crashing when I try to initalize an object. I have the following protocol:

**Protocol**

```
import Foundation

@objc public protocol Client {

    func method()

}
```

**Protocol implementation**

```
import Foundation

public class ClientWhateverImpl : NSObject, Client{

    let name : String

    init(name: name) {
        self.name = name
    }

    public func method(){
      //make something
    }

}
```

**Assembly**

```
import Foundation
import Typhoon

public class MyAssembly: TyphoonAssembly {

    public dynamic func client() -> AnyObject {

        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(ClientWhateverImpl.self) {
            (definition) in

            definition!.useInitializer("initWithName:") {
                (initializer) in

                initializer!.injectParameter(with: "name")
            }

        } as AnyObject
    }



}
```

**Call it somewhere**

```
let myAssembly : MyAssembly = MyAssembly()
        myAssembly.activate()

let client = myAssembly.client()
```

Unfortunately I got the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Method 'initWithName:' not found on 'MyApp.ClientWhateverImpl'. Did you include the required ':' characters to signify arguments?'
```

I read some posts on stackoverflow about this error but on their side they forget to use the objectice-c method syntax. But in my case I use the objc method "initWithName". Is there something different in swift 3? Has someone the same problem?

Comment: did you see the wiki: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Swift-Quick-Start

Comment: i think you need at `ClientWhateverImpl` also the  `TyphoonAssembly`

Comment: What do you mean excatly? I can't see the "Knight"-class in the quick start guide. I used more or less the code of the swift sample app only rewritten in swift 3. Can you maybe write an answer with your suggestion to avoid missunderstandings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the issue. It has something to do with an object which i wanted to inject. It doesn't inherit from `NSObject` and Typhoon makes something with it and fails:

```
definition!.useInitializer("initWithObject:") {
    (initializer) in
    initializer!.injectParameter(with: MyObject())
}
```

**Before:**

```
public class MyObject{

}
```

**Solution:**

```
public class MyObject: NSObject{

}
```

The documentation even says it:

> Every class you want to inject has to be a subclass of NSObject in
>   some way (either by subclassing or adding @objc modifier).

I just thought the `ClientWhateverImpl` in my case has to inherit from `NSObject`. My fault. This is question closed